# How to get values from a list?

Tags: r, list

I have a list with uniform size as below. I want to extract the values for the keys. How do I do it?

I have isolated the keys by using `names(allsum)` where `allsum` looks like this

```
`$1999
[1] 7332967

$2002
[1] 5635780

$2005
[1] 5454703

$2008
[1] 3464206`
```

I want `[7332967, 5635780, 5454703, 3464206]` as the output. I tried `sapply` but have a weak intuition. Please help.

```
for(a in allsum) {
  print(a[[1]])
}
```

I tried this, it works, but I want to know if we can do it with some function or without any explicit looping.

I tried using `unlist`
Following is what happens

```
c1 <- unlist(allsum) 
 #1999    2002    2005    2008 
#7332967 5635780 5454703 3464206
```

I just need the big numbers. How do I extract?

Comment: If you use `lapply` and getting this as an output, consider using [`sapply`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7141669/1030110).

Comment: What you get with just `v1 <- unlist(allsum)` is a named vector, which is still a numeric vector. For example you can try `v1 + 1000` or do `as.data.frame(v1)`, or `names(v1)` and `unname(v1)`

Comment: Perfect @Sotos I thing unname() is the right thing to do!! Thanks!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What about

```
allsum <- list(`1999` = 7332967, `2002` = 5635780, 
               `2005` = 5454703, `2008` = 3464206)   

paste(unlist(allsum))
# [1] "7332967" "5635780" "5454703" "3464206"
```

## Edit:

As pointed out in the comments, `paste` will convert the numerical values in to strings.

You can either solve the problem create by `paste(unlist(allsum))` with:

```
as.numeric(paste(unlist(allsum))
# [1] 7332967 5635780 5454703 3464206
```

Or avoid that issue altogether by using Sotos' suggestion in the comments:

```
unname(unlist(allsum))
# [1] 7332967 5635780 5454703 3464206
```

Comment: Works fine!! Thanks a lot Could you please explain how it works as only using `unlist` we just get both the keys and values

Comment: I would NOT recommend that. It converts the values to character. Why not simply `unname`?

Answer (score 12):

@Sotos thanks a lot.

I think I was just looking for this!!

`unname(unlist(allsum))`

Comment: Also works as `unlist(unname(cols_dict))`.

Answer (score 4):

Please, try

```
as.integer(allsum)
#[1] 7332967 5635780 5454703 3464206
```

Answer (score 0):

To get, the values of list as a vector, you should do:

```
unlist(allsum)
```

Comment: I used the unlist and got the above output